# How to allow users edit thier profile?

Tags: django

I'm new to Django Framework and trying to learning it by making a website which users can post .

I want to allow users to edit their profile after registration but the tutorials i found online was not straight forward and complicated .
like these two :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9Xd6jribFU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CQ90L5jfldw

here is the view.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(response, f'Your account has been created!')
        return redirect("blog-home")
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(response,"register/register.html",{"form":form})

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)


        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        contex={'u_form':user_form, 'p_form':profile_form}
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

and for the profile.html :

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
              {{ user_form|crispy }}
              {{ profile_form|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I would appreciate it if someone help me with this 
Thank you

Comment: add some code to show what you tried so far.

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: you are working on function based views which is quite hard at beginning to understand instead i advise you to work on class based views. I made a compete project on this you can see my project here, https://github.com/YashMarmat/Blog-App-django-v3.git